# Android Scaling for Multiple Resolution Screens

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I am developing an Android application where the server sends all the values corresponding to dimensions in pixels for 1920*1080 resolution device.I need the app to be supported on multiple screen resolutions.I went through Android documentation on supporting multiple screen resolutions.It suggests to convert pixels to dip and then render.I did that in my application but the views are not rendered as required.So I tried applying simple unitary method by dynamically getting the screen width and height and then scaling all dimensions based on current screen width and height.
Say my current screen width is X and height is Y.So what I did was
Scaling factor in horizontal direction = New Screen Width/1920.
Scaled dimension in horizontal direction = Scaling factor in horizontal direction * Dimension from server in horizontal direction.
Similarly for vertical direction.
The application is now looking fine on my device.But is it a reliable way of doing things ? Should I be dealing with density of display too ?

Comment: Do you created the images with respect to the ratios of screen as mention?

Answer (score 0):

DP is probably the better approach, if you elaborate a bit on what you mean by 'not rendered as required' I can try to help.

I can think of two main issues with your current method:

1. Different aspect ratios of devices. Using your method you will end up with distorted imagery. For example a square in 'server dimensions' is 400x400. In a 800x480 phone, that square will be 162x177 - no longer a square. Depending on your visuals and purpose of your app, this may or may not be an issue. If it is an issue, you need to account for that.
2. Physical views' size. One of the purposes of the DP method is to ensure a view will have (almost ) the same size across different devices, mainly never too small to handle for the user. So using the DP approach, a 100dp button will be 200px on a high density device, and 100px on a medium density device. This way the button is physically the same size on both devices. 
   But your method ignores that. Take the square from the first example - it will always be a fifth (400/1920) of the width of the screen. This can be either huge or tiny, depending on the device dimensions. Again, depending on your needs this may or may not be a problem.

Your method can work, as long as you account for these (and maybe more) problems. But it does require special care and probably more coding and work to make it work perfectly compared to simply using DP.

Comment: Thats a very good point but I forgot to mention in the OP that the app needs to support only 1920*1080 and 1280*720 resolutions and for both of them,the (1280/1920) or (720/1080) ratio is same.

Comment: I would still take density into account, just so you don't end up with huge buttons on a tablet, for instance. Considering the aspect ratio is the same you just need to modify your factor a bit to end up with a consistent user experience. But consider that some 1280x720 devices utilize full screen area for apps while other 1280x720 devices reserve some spaces for on-screen soft buttons. So the actual aspect ratio is not equal between Galaxy S3 and Galaxy nexus. If, however, you're using full screen immersive mode then you're good to go.